# Opening and Closing OleDbConnection during Data Processing - is this good form?

Tags: c#, ado.net, oledb

Is this a good way to process data, i dont like the idea of copying the open close connection all over the place. In essence, is this good form/style?

Data Processing Method:

```
    public int Process(Func<Product, OleDbConnection, int> func, Product data)
    {
        var oleConnect = new OleDbConnection { ConnectionString = @"stuff" };
        oleConnect.Open();
        oleConnect.ChangeDatabase("InventoryManager");
        var ret = func(data, oleConnect);
        oleConnect.Close();
        return ret;
    }
```

Typical Method used by the Func:
(Update, Delete, Select are the others to pass)

```
    public int Insert(Product data, OleDbConnection oleConnect)
    {
        var oleCommand = new OleDbCommand("pInsProduct", oleConnect) { CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure };
        oleCommand.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@ProductId", data.ProductID));
        oleCommand.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@ProductName", data.ProductName));

        return oleCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
```

The usage code ends up more or less written as:

```
Process(Insert, data);
Process(Update, data);
```

EDIT:
I thought up the following alternative method, which is a better implementation? (using's aside):
(open connection more or less equals the Process method above)

```
int Insert(Product data)
{
    Using ( OleDbConnection oleConnect = OpenConnection() )
    {
        //do stuff
        oleConnect.Close(); // maybe redundant with Using statement?
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you should be making sure to wrap your connections in `using` statements to ensure that the connections get closed and disposed of properly. You should do the same for commands. In the end, it is fine to open and close connections like that as typically you won't pay a penalty due to connection pooling, but you still want to re-use connections as much as you can, so do so whenever possible as long as you make sure you close / clean up when done.